# Изменение размера картинки (Android)

Tags: android, java, canvas

Есть код:

```
Bitmap cBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b1s12);
canvas.drawBitmap(cBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Проблема в том, что картинка выводится в своём оригинальном размере. Как растянуть её на весь экран?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя метод `drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)`:

> **Draw the specified bitmap, scaling/translating automatically to fill the destination rectangle.** If the source rectangle is not null, it specifies the subset of the bitmap to draw.
>
> …
>
> *Parameters*
>
> `bitmap`  The bitmap to be drawn
>
> `src`     May be null. The subset of the bitmap to be drawn
>
> **`dst`       The rectangle that the bitmap will be scaled/translated to fit into**
>
> `paint`   May be null. The paint used to draw the bitmap